# Using DYP-ME007Y-PWM Ultrasonic sensor

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I actually want to use this waterproof ultrasonic sensor DYP-ME007Y-PWM (http://hanjindata.lgnas.com:10000/myweb/P0400/P0400.pdf) on my raspberry PI Compute Module on a classic Raspbian OS. It has 4 pin's (gnd,Trig,Echo and 5V).
Here is my schematic:

```
Raspberry Pi |  Sensor
GND          | GND
5V           | 5V
22           | Trig
23           | Echo
```

I've found some tutorials that explain how ultrasonic sensors works and mannage to have good results with other kind of ultrasonic sensors like this one for exemple (http://www.micropik.com/PDF/HCSR04.pdf)

Here is my code :

```
# Import required Python libraries
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

# Use BCM GPIO references
# instead of physical pin numbers
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# Define GPIO to use on Pi
GPIO_TRIGGER = 22
GPIO_ECHO = 23

print "Ultrasonic Measurement"

# Set pins as output and input
GPIO.setup(GPIO_TRIGGER,GPIO.OUT)  # Trigger
GPIO.setup(GPIO_ECHO,GPIO.IN)      # Echo

# Set trigger to False (Low)
GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, False)

# Allow module to settle
time.sleep(0.5)

# Send 10us pulse to trigger
while True:
    GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, True)
    time.sleep(0.00001)
    GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, False)

    start = time.time()
    while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO)==0:
      start = time.time()

    while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO)==1:
      stop = time.time()

    # Calculate pulse length
    elapsed = stop-start
    # Distance pulse travelled in that time is time
    # multiplied by the speed of sound (cm/s)
    # That was the distance there and back so halve the value
    distance = (elapsed * 34000)/2

    print "Distance : %.1f" % distance
    time.sleep(0.05)
# Reset GPIO settings
GPIO.cleanup()
```

I doesn't work, i obtain always the same output whatever i do with my sensor
Does anybody has alreeady play with this sensor ? As you can see, the datasheet is pretty ligth, so maybe you will see something my poor electronics skills have missed

Greetings !

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting `GPIO_ECHO` to be **1** from the start. According to the documentation it is first **0**, then **1**, and then back to 
**1**.

Maybe

```
while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO)==0:
    # some short sleep might be better
    pass 

start = time.time()

while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO)==1: 
    pass

while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO)==0:
    pass

stop = time.time()
```

There are methods available for detecting rising edge and falling edge, see for example [raspi.tv arcticle](http://raspi.tv/2014/rpi-gpio-update-and-detecting-both-rising-and-falling-edges). It might be better to use those methods.

Answer (score 0):

According to:

https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=153700.30

the sensor is quite sensitive to getting enough power - Check that your 5V doesn't drop too much.

Also the Raspberry Pi GPIO pins are 3V3 - They might not like the output from the sensor (which presumably is 5V), and the sensor might not trigger on the 3V3 output from the Raspberry pi.